# How to determine the theoretical ACF of a SARIMA model?

Tags: time-series, arima, acf-pacf

I need to determine the ACF for a SARIMA(0,0,1)(0,0,1)<sub>12</sub> model with $\Theta=0.7$ and $\theta=0.4$. However, I am unsure what parameters to use.

Comment: Would you like to write out "your model"? It will then be easy for you to find the acf :-)